# Borda diagonal nos cantos da página

Tags: css, css3

Estou estudando a respeito de bordas em diagonal e pretendo aplicar um efeito como este na minha página:

[image: borda diagonal]

Até o momento achei pouco material a respeito e o mais próximo foi esse:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: tomato;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
          transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 774px;
  height: 500%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 8px 10000px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50px) translateX(-598px);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50px) translateX(-598px);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  min-height: 380px;
  padding: 2em;
}

.centered {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: tomato;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="centered">
      pseudo isometric diagonal stripe border woop!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/hudakdidit/pen/kbztp)**

Mas não estou conseguindo aplicar nem entender essa lógica.

Comment: Isso tem mais cara de uma div (ou pseudoelemento) com listas e outra div branca dentro. Tem infinitas maneiras de fazer o que quer, seria importante [edit] o post e especificar melhor o contexto. Provavelmente um [mcve] do que tentou seria um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Ia postar como resposta, mas como já tem o suficiente: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Begjya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, eu aqui usei duas técnicas basicamente, um `pseudo-elemento` e coloquei nele um `repeating-linear-gradient`. O elemento principal tem a cor de fundo branca, e as listrinhas ficam só no pseudo elemento com o `repeating-linear-gradient` em `-45deg` para ficar inclinadom

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.box::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: calc(100% + 20px);
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0px, black 10px, yellow 10px, yellow 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa unde enim culpa consectetur ut expedita quia adipisci repudiandae voluptate quisquam architecto, iste totam autem optio ipsam rem accusantium sint magni!
</div>
```

Comment: deu para entender perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: @PatriqueAlves fico feliz em ter ajudado! Se vc quiser ler mais sobre o linear-gradiente aqui tem um link didático https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 3):

Crie uma div pai e uma div filha e coloque um background `linear-gradient` com duas cores na div pai, e na div filha você coloca um fundo branco. O `padding` na div pai dará o efeito de que é uma borda:

```css
.pai{
   width: 300px;
   padding: 20px; /* largura da borda */
   background: repeating-linear-gradient(
     -45deg,
     #F3F900,
     #F3F900 10px,
     #000 10px,
     #000 20px
   );
}

.filho{
   padding: 20px;
   background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
   <div class="filho">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
   </div>
</div>
```

Você pode alterar as cores e a largura das faixas (onde tem `10px`).

Comment: entendi a logica agora, obrigado pela ajuda.